# QML TextInput : How to detect user has completed typing on the text field

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I am new to Qt & QML. I am using QtQuick 2.4. I have `TextInput` item with a signal defined in a `qml` file like below:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

TextInput {
  text: "Text"
  cursorVisible: true

  signal qmlSignal(string msg)
}
```

I also have a slot tied to the `qmlSignal`. I want to trigger the signal when user completes typing on the `TextInput` field or closes my qml page to go to another page in the application.

*What is the correct way to acheive this desired functionality ? Is there something like `onFocusChanged false` that I can detect, & fire the qml signal ?*

I tried searching but couldn't get a sample of how to do this in qml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the [`editingFinished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#editingFinished-signal) signal?

> This signal is emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the
>   text input loses focus.

Comment: I am doing this for touch screen android & ios phones. Should work there as well. right ?

Comment: @NelsonP - It should.

Comment: how should I change the `TextInput` qml block to send the text when `editingFinished` is signalled ? can u pls provide a sample. I am a newbie to this

Comment: `onEditingFinished: qmlSignal(text)`

Comment: doesnt work. it errors as `invalid property` & app crashes. I am putting it like so     

    `TextInput {
      text: "Text"
      cursorVisible: true

      signal qmlSignal(string msg)

      onEditingFinished: qmlSignal(text)
    }`

Comment: may be I am missing some `import statement` to make this work ?

Comment: Just type that under the declaration of your signal

Comment: if I do this it works: `onTextChanged: {
                console.log(text)
            }` Dont find any `onEditingFinished` there. this might be something with the qtquick imports

Comment: It is a member of TextInput, read the documentation. I have linked to it.

Comment: That won't fire if you have an input mask or validator set... which makes the control nearly useless (because you can't detect when the user is done).